# junit cannot find class

Tags: java, junit4

1. I am able to run the sample tests supplied with junit (from any directory). I would think that this suggests my installation of junit is perfectly fine.
2. I assume, to compile a junit test, it is no different from any other java file, namely: javac fileName.java
3. My test file (.java and resulting .class) lives in: c:\parent\child. Obviously, in order to compile the .java file, I have a package statement on the first line: package parent.child followed by the all-important: import junit.framework.TestCase;  After this, there is a public class fileName definition extends TestCase {}.
   The file compiles without any warnings or errors.
4. when I attempt (in the c:\parent\child directory where fileName exists, both the .java and .class):

> java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore parent.child.fileName, I get the following:
>   JUnit version 4.1 Could not find class: parent.child.fileName Time: 0
>   OK (0 tests)

5. Even if I drop parent.child altogether from the command, it makes no difference.
6. My CLASSPATH environment variable is set to:
   c:\parent\junit\junit-4.1.jar;c:\parent\junit;.
7. If I trying running with -cp c:\ or c:\parent\child or anything else, I still get the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java package names are actually part of the class name, and they're also used in a specific way to find `*.class` files. If Java wants to find a class named `parent.child.fileName`, it's going to look for a file named `parent/child/fileName.class` -- i.e., it's going to look for the file in a directory named `child` in a directory named `parent`. You have to specify the class path such that the `parent` directory will be found, something like

```
 java -cp "c:/junit/junit.jar;c:/" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore parent.child.fileName
```

The class path (-cp) argument has to specify all the places that Java should look for classes, including jar files like `junit.jar`, which I've imagined is located in a directory called `junit`. The semicolon ";" is used to separate entries on the class path (assuming you're using Windows; on real computers it's a ":" instead.) The "c:/" entry in the class path is the one that will be used to find the `parent` directory and thus your class.

Comment: I am quite confused by your response. Indicating a classpath, as you have indicated above is not needed. I already have an environment variable set. As mentioned in my first numbered comment, I am able to run the sample tests from anywhere, using the supplied (in the document) command: java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore org.junit.tests.AllTests

Comment: The class path you have set in the environment  variable does not include c:\ , the location of the test class you wrote yourself. The error message clearly states that your test class cannot be found.

Comment: Ernest Friedman-Hill... you are the real deal... thanks... Amazing how many people are not! (Yes, I knew what the error message said, but was befuddled as to why it could not find the class).

Comment: though rather than c:/, I had to use c:\ in the windows environment setting; your original command line version did not work for me (and I will try undoing the environment variable and see why)

Comment: further confusing matters was the fact the original code (against which the test case was written), was working fine as is...

Comment: Windows will accept "/" instead of "\" in paths in many cases, but not in all. I apologize if this is one of those cases.

Comment: Of course, semicolon is used to separate items, even in grammar, it would make sense to have it, on "special" computers they had to use the colon to overcomplicate things.

Answer (score -1):

You should use JUnit Runner to run test outside IDE, not only compile it.

```
java -cp lib/junit.jar;sw.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore your.package.fileName
```

update this line to yours project structure.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the error message he's seeing, so I'm not sure why you've told him to do this.

Comment: yes... I was using JUnit Runner to run the test file... otherwise I would not have had the output indicated in my fourth comment.

Answer (score -2):

In general it's so much easier to run unit tests using a build system like ant/maven/gradle or from within your IDE (IntelliJ/eclipse/Netbeans)

Comment: It's pretty important to learn how this stuff actually works, though, and the sooner the better. If all you know how to do is push a button, then you're dead in the water when things break for some reason.

Comment: I don't agree at all with the notion that beginners should start at the command line with notepad so that they learn how things really work. In my experience it's way more useful to discover programming in a simpler environment and then slowly expand as you go along.

Comment: Hmmm... Yes, it may be "easier" to use an IDE after you know how to use an IDE and its general concepts, but its another layer of potential mistakes and misunderstandings. Given the trivial documentation to JUnit, it should be much, much easier than what I have experienced.

Comment: Sure, there is some setup required to get going with an IDE but at least at the end of that setup you have a good working environment which is not something that can be said of the commandline solution.

Comment: Sorry, but that really does not help. I do not want to deal with an IDE at this point.

Comment: Downvoted for many of the same reasons as others pointed out--this isn't an answer to the question, and it's bad technology practice to avoid understanding a problem.