# How to get JUnit 4.11 to recognize class in default package?

Tags: java, junit, jar, import, junit4

Similar to other questions on this subject, I am having problems getting JUnit 4.11 to recognize my class.

Similar to the question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481269/how-do-i-import-jars-into-my-java-program), I am using algs4.jar to write a class, Percolation, which is all in the default package. Just as in the post I linked, I too had difficulty importing algs4 into my class to use the required WeightedWuickUnionUF class found within. I was finally able to compile the program with the following setup.

```
> echo $CLASSPATH
/Users/dj/Library/Java/Extensions/algs4.jar:
/Users/dj/Library/Java/Extensions/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:
/Users/dj/Library/Java/Extensions/junit-4.11.jar:
/Users/dj/Library/Java/Extensions/stdlib.jar
```

Percolation.java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import algs4.*;

public class Percolation {

    private WeightedQuickUnionUF union_find_ds;
    ...
}
```

test_Percolation.java

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert.*;

@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class test_Percolation{
    
    private static Percolation perc;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void testSetup(){
        perc = new Percolation(5); 
    }   
    @AfterClass
    public static void testCleanup(){
        perc = null;
    }   

    @Test(expected = IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
    public void testIndexErrorThrown(){
        perc.open(0,5);
    }   
}
```

Compilation was accomplished with the following commands. Both .java files are in the same folder, so too is a directory titled algs4.jar with the algs4.jar fully expanded such that each class exists as its own file. Therefore in the working directory there are the following files.

```
Percolation.java
test_Percolation.java
algs4/WeightedQuickUnionUF.class
```

I feel that this is an important point because even though algs4.jar is within the classpath, the Percolation.java file ONLY compiles when I have algs4/WeightedQuickUnionUF.class in the current working directory. For some reason I cannot get the import to work with the .jar in the classpath.

```
>javac Percolation.java
>javac test_Percolation.java
```

Please note that in Percolation.java if I changed the import line from `import algs4.*;` to `import algs4.WeightedQuickUnionUF;` I receive the following error at compile time.

```
Percolation.java:23: error: cannot access WeightedQuickUnionUF
import algs4.WeightedQuickUnionUF;
            ^
  bad class file: ./algs4/WeightedQuickUnionUF.class
    class file contains wrong class: WeightedQuickUnionUF
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

Having compiled both files successfully, I attempted to use the solutions found from the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548580/junit-cannot-find-class). Entering the command `java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore test_Percolation` or the more verbose but seemingly unecessary command `java -cp /Users/dj/Library/Java/Extensions/junit-4.11.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore test_Percolation` both yield the following error.

```
JUnit version 4.11
Could not find class: test_Percolation

Time: 0.002

OK (0 tests)
```

I suspect that there is something wrong with my system configuration on top of the effects of my limited knowledge of Java and importing using Java. I know these questions have been posted elsewhere, but the solutions to said questions have not worked on my machine. Perhaps I have missed a nuance of the answers to other questions.

I am using Mac OSX 10.8.5 doing all of the programming and compilling from the command line using javac 1.7.0_07.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your command-line:

```
java -cp /Users/dj/Library/Java/Extensions/junit-4.11.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
```

You've got the JUnit jar file on your class path - but not the current directory. So it won't be able to find *any* classes that aren't either "system" classes or in JUnit.

Try something like:

```
java -cp .:/Users/dj/Library/Java/Extensions/junit-4.11.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
```

Ideally you should *also* start using packages though - and using more conventional class names. (`test_Percolation` violates normal conventions.)

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion regarding conventional class names. As I don't typically use Java, I am not well versed in such conventions. Regarding your suggested fix, it did not work. I tried typing the command as you suggested and received the same error. I also appended `CLASSPATH` to contain the current directory. Neither attempt worked.

Comment: @vckngs7: Did the error message change? Are you *in* the directory containing the class file for `test_Percolation`? Note that your other error message sounds like it's a different error - you need to sort out which package you want `WeightedQuickUnionUF` to be in, and declare that in the source code.

Comment: The error message did not change. And yes, I am in the directory containing test_Percolation. Regarding the second error message, I am not sure what you mean by sorting out which package I want WeightedQuickUnionUF to be in and delcare that in the source. WeightedQuickUnionUF was written by someone else and assembled into the algs4.jar for convenience. It is not code that I wrote, I simply want to use the class.

Comment: @vckngs7: Well it sounds like it's *not* in a package at the moment, so don't try to import it as if it is. So just to check, you have the *compiled* class (i.e. the `test_Percolation.class` file in the current directory? Not just the source file?

Comment: Yes, you are correct that the `.class` file is in the current directory. As for the import, how does one ust another class if it is not within a package? Ideally I would like to use the WeightedQuickUnionUF that is found in `algs4.jar` within the `~/Library/Java/Extensions/` directory.

Comment: @vckngs7: As your class isn't within a package either, you shouldn't need to import it. But frankly *both* classes should be in packages. And this doesn't sound like a suitable class to put in the extensions directory, really...

Comment: Perhaps not, but do such violations of convention point to why JUnit is unable to find my class? Is there a straightforward guide to such conventions I can read up on for future reference?

Comment: @vckngs7: No, the convention violations aren't the problem here. Unfortunately SO isn't really designed to be an interactive debugging tool - I think we've reached the end of how I can help you here. As for naming conventions, for some reason the official Sun (now Oracle) guide is currently unavailable, but you might want to read the Google Java style guide instead: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html